# How do I renew an SSL certificate for several years in IIS?

Tags: iis, ssl

The renewal wizard doesn't seem to ask for a renewal period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Cerficate Supplier sets the renewal period.  So it depends on the type of Cert you buy (or the setup of your certification service).

Answer (score 0):

The expiration date of the certificate you buy/create would define that

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked trying to use any cert that is good for more than one year causes the client to reject it anyway.